# Windows bootcamp partition still present, unrecognized?

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning, boot-camp

So I recently got a computer that came partitioned via bootcamp with windows 7 and OSX 10.7. It had the ratio of Mac to Windows 1 to 2, and I preferred it to be the other way around. So I went in and shrank the windows partition. Somehow, I messed up, and deleted the mac partition. So, I created a new partition, installed OSX 10.8 on it, and now the windows partition is gone.

Here's where it gets strange:

The windows partition still shows up, but not on the boot screen. Only on the desktop after the boot. All the files and folders are still there.

The other problem is that I do not have the windows 7 install disk, so I can't simply wipe the whole thing and start over (which I would much rather do).

Comment: Provided you have the authentication key there are mirriors to official WIndows 7 isos on digital river which Microsoft uses to distrubute digital versions of Windows 7.  There is a question which contain the links.  As how to solve the problem bootcamp partition is connnected to the installation of OS X that created it.